# Is the beta-binomial model appropriate for modelling weekly rain day counts?

Tags: probability, bayesian, modeling, inference, stochastic-processes

I would like to implement Bayesian estimation [1, 2] to test for differences between the means of weekly wet day counts (days with observed precipitation > 0.2mm [3]) for a city in Canada using two datasets: one containing historical precipitation data from 2010-2016 and another containing precipitation data for this year (2017).  As 2017 is not yet complete, the historical dataset excludes weeks that have not yet been observed in 2017.

The distributions appear to be $Binom(7,p_{hist})$ and $Binom(7,p_{2017}$):

[image: Weekly wet day count distributions]

I've set up a beta-binomial model such that $p_{hist} \sim Beta(\alpha_{hist},\beta_{hist})$ and $p_{2017} \sim Beta(\alpha_{2017},\beta_{2017})$ where the alphas and betas are set to the effective number of observations [4] of wet days and non-wet days, respectively.  After performing inference, the difference of means (Beta distributions) is distributed as:

[image: Difference of wet day count means]

providing overwhelming evidence that there is indeed a difference.

My question is really whether or not this model is appropriate since day-to-day precipitation is clearly not independent, violating the independence assumption of Bernoulli trials which is necessary in modelling the weekly wet day counts as being binomially distributed.  I'm unsure as to what the criteria is for relaxing the assumption both in this application and in general.  Any guidance would be most appreciated.

1. http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/BEST/BEST.pdf
2. https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/BEST.html
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_of_precipitation#Environment_Canada
4. Bishop, C. (2006) Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning.

Comment: comment, not a full answer: although the beta-binomial models departure from the binomial model as non-homogeneity rather than non-independence, these two potential   are confounded in your sample. Unless you're set on a mechanistic model whose parameters will directly give a measure of non-independence, I *personally* would feel quite comfortable using B-B to model the departure from binomial (particularly since the assumptions of both homogeneity and independence are likely to be violated).

Comment: I understand that you have the # of wet days by week for some 7-8 years . Please provide a csv file of this data and I will see what I can do with time series magical tricks..